# Word to describe "continuous relationship" between predictor and outcome variable

Tags: writing, terminology

I'm writing my methods section where I want to stress that I am not looking at the effect by condition, but exploring the continuous relationship between my predictor variable and the dependent variable. Both are continuous variables in my analysis, but the original study where the data comes from bins the predictor variable by High and Low, and just looks are the main effect of condition (High/Low), so I'm trying to clarify that this is not what I'm doing here.

"We are interested in the **continuous** effect of Y on X, rather than the overall effect of condition". I feel like "continuous" is not clear/misleading. I feel like there must be a proper term for what I'm trying to say, perhaps something obvious, but I can't think of what this is called.

Comment: I'm a bit uncertain as to what you are dealing with, but my initial thought is that some version of ["continuum model"](https://www.google.com/search?q=continuum+model) might be appropriate. The primary origin of the notion, at least from what I know, is from [continuum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics), but the term is now often used in other situations. For example, beginning with [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=continuum+discrete+model), add various words such as "business", "biology", "predator-prey", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Continuous" is standard terminology for variables and their relationships in statistics.

I would explain explicitly what differentiates your current paper from previous work: e.g., previously X was dichotomized as high/low, whereas you are using X as a continuous variable. Might also be worth emphasizing whether X is actually continuous or not (some examples where you might treat X as continuous from a modeling sense would include counts or other fine-scale but technically discrete variables like a score that takes only integers, or even clearly discrete items like Likert scores that nonetheless often behave acceptably when treated as continuous). That is, distinguish between *variables* that are continuous and *approaches to analysis* that treat them as such.

The part that feels wrong to me in your sentence is:

> rather than the overall effect of condition

There's no "rather" here; a continuous relationship might as well be an overall effect, though that sort of phrasing typically comes up in ANOVA contexts where an F-test of the hypothesis that some factor with more than 2 levels has an effect, without specifying which levels, is described as "overall". In your case I might say "rather than binarized/categorical coding of condition".

Comment: What are some examples of non-continuous relationships? Having continuous variables discretized is common, and it is a standard terminology indeed (stats.SE has a bunch of examples), but I would find "discrete relationship" to be a confusing term, especially with mixed data when it is used to describe a disjoint family of functions. Underlining that the variable can be treated as continuous and one can use metrics without e.g. one-hot encoding first makes sense to me, but that is still speaking about variables, not relationships.

Comment: @Lodinn I'd recommend describing variables as continuous and then making clear how you are relating them; e.g., a linear relationship between continuous variables. I don't think I've recommended using the phrase "discrete relationship", but any association between a factor and another variable is not a continuous relationship.

Comment: @Lodinn Well, sex/gender for one.

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks, that's helpful. I agree with your comment on the "rather..." wording as well, rephrased that bit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

While "continuous" is pretty obvious to a mathematician, it might not be in your own field. But "fine-grained" might work, though it isn't the same thing mathematically. In some fields, "deterministic" might also work if small changes in one variable lead to predictable changes in the other.

But if your methodology just uses (lots) more "bins" then "fine-grained" is pretty accurate.